# Initialize text file and store in array

Tags: c, arrays

Hello I'm creating a function that will read all words in a text file and store each in an array (WordA[]). Here's my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "dictionary.h" 
void
InitializeWords(char *WordA[])
{
    char word[31];
    int i;
    FILE *filep;

    filep = fopen("bacon.txt", "r");

    if (fp != NULL) { // means that file exists 
        for (i=0; i<NWORDS; i++){
          fscanf(filep, "%s", word);
          strcpy(WordA[i], word);
       }
       fclose(filep);
    }

}
```

The words that will be initialized here in `WordA[]` will be used in the later part of my program. I've traced where my error is and apparently when I remove the `strcpy (WordA[i], word)`, the words seem to be printing/ read properly.

`InitializeWords` is called in the main function:

```
int
main()
{
    char *WordA[NWORDS]; // a 1D array of character pointers (addresses)

    InitializeWords(WordA); 
    StartGame(WordA);  // starts the program game

    return 0;   

}
```

I dont understand what's wrong in copying the word in the array. Please help! Thank you very much!

Comment: Also please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us. Including how you call this `InitializeWords` function, and what you pass to it.

Comment: What is the definition of `WordA`?

Comment: Please read the comment of "Somme programmer dude" and do what he is asking. Otherwise it's hard for us to help.

Comment: Well this is a pretty simple error, `WordA[i]` is not allocated. You just allocate the WordA but all of is pointer are not !

Comment: In the `main` function you have an array of `NWORDS` pointers. But where do those pointers actually point? Perhaps you should have an array of arrays of characters?

Comment: Lastly, in your call to `fscanf`, what if a "word" is longer than 30 characters? Use e.g. `"%30s"` as the format to not risk overflow of the `word` array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need this (attention: this is minimal, non error checking code, there is still room for improvement).

```
 for (i = 0; i<NWORDS; i++) {
   fscanf(filep, "%30s", word);
    WordA[i] = malloc(strlen(word) + 1);  // <<<< added this line
    strcpy(WordA[i], word);
 }
```

`WordA` is an array of uninitialized pointers. So you need to allocate memory for each of the words using `malloc(strlen(word) + 1);`. The +1 if because of the NUL string terminator.

At the end of the program you should free the allocated memory like this:

```
void FreeWords(char *WordA[])
{
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i<NWORDS; i++) {
    free(WordA[i]);
  }
}
...
FreeWord(WordA);
```

Comment: You should also add the code in order to free the allocated memory ;)

Comment: yup that did the job. i did not allocate memory space and freed them. thanks!